# cocoa: centre align a subview(NSButton) in view programmatically

Tags: macos, cocoa, desktop

I want to Horizontally  Center align a subview(NSButton) in Parentview. I want to do this programmatically.

Comment: my view resizes...so i want to put constraint such that the subview is always horizontally center aligned with respect to the superview.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `myButton` is an `NSButton *`, then:

```
- (void)setFrame:(NSRect)frameRect
{
    [super setFrame:frameRect];

    NSRect buttonRect = [myButton frame];
    buttonRect.origin.x = (NSWidth(frameRect) / 2.0) - (NSWidth(buttonRect) / 2.0);
    [myButton setFrame:buttonRect];
}
```

Comment: I did this...but i want my button to be in center when window size changes..that is it should always be in the center whatever be the width of superview.

Comment: @user1624110 OK, updated.  Move the code into your subclassed `setFrame:` method.